# How to pattern match nested records in Java 22

Tags: java, pattern-matching, java-22

In the following:

```java
sealed interface Uninteresting permits Outer, Inner, InnerInner{ }

record Outer(Inner inner, int x) implements Uninteresting { }

record Inner(InnerInner innerInner, int y) implements Uninteresting { }

record InnerInner(int z) implements Uninteresting { }

void test() {
    var outer = new Outer(new Inner(new InnerInner(3), 4), 2);
    switch (outer) {
        case Outer(Inner(InnerInner(var z), var y), var x) -> {
            System.out.println(z);
            System.out.println(y);
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(outer);
            System.out.println(i); // <- how to reference the Inner? 
            System.out.println(ii); // <- how to reference the InnerInner?
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to name the `Inner` and `InnerInner` objects I match against. It seems that I can use nested switch statements for this:

```java
    switch (outer) {
        case Outer(var i, var x) -> {
            switch (i) {
                case Inner(var ii, var y) -> {
                    switch (ii) {
                        case InnerInner(var z) -> {
                            System.out.println(z);
                            System.out.println(y);
                            System.out.println(x);
                            System.out.println(outer);
                            System.out.println(i);
                            System.out.println(ii);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In Scala, I can use `i@Inner` and `ii@InnerInner` in my match, which would be something like:

```scala
case Outer(i@Inner(ii@InnerInner(var z), var y), var x)
```

Is there a more succinct way to write this sort of logic in modern Java?

Comment: I think there is none, stick to scala ;) Not similar to scala anyways.

Comment: So why would you be intrested in i and ii anyways? As x,y,z are the only variables. What is the point in having a reference to the class?

Comment: Support for named patterns has been dropped in Java 20.